# How to connect wrapper DLL to the API DLL for use in the C# project?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I use [Dynamic Audio Normalizer](https://github.com/lordmulder/DynamicAudioNormalizer) for my WF solution to normalize audio file volume. It has two .dll libraries that must be connected to the project for usage. One of them - .NET library is connected well, the other one - API cannot be to the project at all. Whilst runtime I get a `FileNotFound` exception that's deatiled descrition

> Could not load file or assembly "DynamicAudioNormalizerNET.dll" or one of its dependencies .

Also it is written in the documentation that

> Microsoft.NET-based Application → Use the DynamicAudioNormalizerNET C++/CLI wrapper class, provided by the DynamicAudioNormalizerNET.dll assembly, requires DynamicAudioNormalizerAPI.dll at runtime.

It's dependency is of course "DynamicAudioNormalizerAPI.dll", but it is in the solution's folder as well as the NET.dll. Also both libraries are added to the solution as files and their "Copy to output" feature is set to "Copy always". How can I link this two DLL or just make it run properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two probable reasons.

1. The first reason could be that `DynamicAudioNormalizerAPI.dll` is not placed together with `DynamicAudioNormalizerNET.dll`. Check `Copy local` refference property (in Solution Explorer) and Make sure that these two dlls comes together.
2. `DynamicAudioNormalizerAPI.dll` could have its own unresolved dependencies. You can easily check this by opening `.dll` with special tool [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com). It will show you if you also need some `runtime` or something.

Comment: What does "comes together" in the first explanation mean? The "Copy local" feature is set to true. The API DLL does not include to the project by references, taking me back this:
**A reference to '...\DynamicAudioNormalizerAPI.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.**
Also I get the API depencedcy through this tool, but what should I do then?

Comment: @АртурФокс `"comes together"` means that everythere you see `DynamicAudioNormalizerNET.dll` in your filesystem (there could be many copies) you have to ensure or place `DynamicAudioNormalizerAPI.dll`. So in `My Computer` there must be two `.dll` together `DynamicAudioNormalizerNET.dll` and `DynamicAudioNormalizerAPI.dll`. Place the download link (and your .net version) in Question and I'll test myself.

Comment: it is .NET 4,5 and these files https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3b7q48uawbzno3y/AAC8trJDhQiHNohA8rVX9Tzsa?dl=0.

Comment: `Dependency Walker` shows that `PTHREADVC2.DLL` is missing. Also don't forget that your program became x64 only (since DynamicAudioNormalizerAPI.dll compiled for x64 platform).

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

> It's dependency is of course "DynamicAudioNormalizerAPI.dll", but it is in the solution's folder as well

It needs to be in your projekt output directory (e.g. `bin\debug` or `bin\release`, where your .exe is), not the solution folder.

Comment: It is, beacause I had added it into the project and than have set up it`s "copy into the release and debug folders" feature.

Comment: You should include that info in your question